# What does it mean when Reaver returns a PIN but no passphrase?

Tags: passwords, wifi, wpa2, passphrase, wps

Usually when it's done, the WPA passphrase/password is listed immediately below the WPS PIN.

Any idea what it means when it's absent from the results?

I also tried entering the PIN directly, using the `-p`(`--pin=`) flags to no avail. Here's what it looks like:

[image: WPS PIN]

---

FYI: I'm using the (green) *Alfa AWUS036NH*; with which I've had much success in the past. It uses the *Ralink RT3070* chipset. [image: AWUS036NH]

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens if the router has the PBC (Push Button Connect) activated. The wps pin is the correct but then you can't get the password. So you'll need to push physically the button on router.

Sometimes this behavior can be because a bad signal. You can try closer to the AP.

Other times it depends of the compatibility of your chipsed and the software. For example, if you have a Ralink chipset on your wireless card, Reaver doesn't work very well. If this is your case you can use the alternative to reaver (bully).

**EDIT**:

Another idea... Did you tried using -N (--no-nacks) parameter?

**EDIT2**

I found this, maybe it can help you: https://gitlab.com/billhibadb/reaver-wps/issues/203

Comment: I typically do use a Ralink chipset. I've had a lot of success with it in the past. Can you provide any evidence of this? I don't not believe you; but would like to be thorough. Thanks for writing in.

Comment: This is only my experience... ralink+reaver=problems . Try bully!!!! you'll success with ralink!

Comment: Yes, in this case the `-N` (`--no-nacks`) parameter was required to succeed.

Comment: Nope. That's purely an incidental comment. I used the `--no-nacks` method as a result of some trial & error when I noticed the AP wouldn't play ball without it. That was at least 2-3 weeks ago, before I asked the question. All up, (including AP lockouts) it took over 600,000 seconds (about 7 days) to crack the WPS PIN. The WPS PIN was not accompanied by a WPA(2) passcode. It's my first time encountering this aberrant behaviour.

Comment: I'm based on my own experience. I experienced same behavior like you (only pin cracked, not password) using reaver and using bully I got the password. Curiously I have the exactly same Alfa and Ralink chipset. So, not sure how to demonstrate it to you. I'll google to try to find something... but in the mean time you can try bully. Believe me, it worked. I think you have nothing to lose trying.

Comment: Also, I have an *AWUS036NHA* (*Atheros AR9271*) and *AWUS036H* (*Realtek 8187L*). So I will try them as well, and we will get to the bottom of this.

Comment: I started an official `#reaver` IRC channel @ irc://chat.freenode.net a while back; if you're interested in discussing it further.